# React reading data form the server

Tags: reactjs, graphql, strapi

I am getting an error from strapi backend data when I fetch particular data into the front end react app I get an error when I log the data into the browser console I see my data in the browser console.

```
query GetPromoProducts {
    allStrapiProduct(filter: {promo: {eq: true}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          strapiId
          name
          variants {
            images {
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)


const [selectedSlides, setSelectedSlides] = useState(0)

console.log(data);

var slides =  [];

data.allStrapiProduct.edges.map(({node}) => {
  console.log(node.variants[0].images[0]);
})
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Add null checking via [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and more `console.log`s. One of your rows has empty data somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Debugging

To debug the server side, use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log) to work your way up to the object's that returning null.

Not sure what the exact code looks like, based on question.

```
const myQuery = graphql`
  query GetPromoProducts {
    allStrapiProduct(filter: { promo: { eq: true } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          strapiId
          name
          variants {
            images {
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Component = () => {
  const [selectedSlides, setSelectedSlides] = useState(0);

  console.log(data);

  data.allStrapiProduct.edges.map(({ node }) => {
    // For this case, use optional chaining to work your way up the tree
    console.log(node);
    console.log(node?.variants);
    console.log(node?.variants?.[0]);
    console.log(node?.variants?.[0]?.images);
    console.log(node?.variants?.[0]?.images?.[0]);
  });
};
```

To stop right at the area this happens:

```
data.allStrapiProduct.edges.map(({ node }) => {
  if (!node?.variants?.[0]?.images?.length) {
    console.log(node);
    console.log(node?.variants);
    console.log(node?.variants?.[0]);
    console.log(node?.variants?.[0]?.images);
    console.log(node?.variants?.[0]?.images?.[0]);
    throw "Required data missing";
  }
});
```

### Resilient React with GraphQL

GraphQL structured data may be typed, but unless the fields are required, you have to handle `null`.

To make the client-side code more robust, you can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to skip objects with no images, or - as in this example - make components handle the case where data is missing. It's entirely up to how you want the frontend app to render it.

I haven't tested this code, so take it as "pseudo-JSX" to demonstrate handling empty graphql response fields.

```
const ProductVariant = ({ variant }) => {
  if (!variant) return null;

  return (
    <div className="variant">
      {variant?.images?.map?.((image, idx) => (
        <img src={url} key={idx} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const ProductVariants = ({ variants }) => {
  if (!variants?.length > 0) return null;

  return (
    <div className="variant-list">
      <div>Variants</div>
      <div className="variant-list--items">
        {variants?.map?.((variant, idx) => (
          <ProductVariant variant={variant} key={idx} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Products = () => {
  const [selectedSlides, setSelectedSlides] = useState(0);

  console.log(data);

  const products = data.allStrapiProduct.edges.map(({ node }) => {
    // Handle as you deem fit
  });

  return (
    <div id="products">
      <p>Here is a list of products</p>
      <div className="products">
        {products?.map?.((product, idx) => {
          return (
            <div className="product" key={idx}>
              {product?.variants?.length > 1 && (
                <ProductVariants variants={variants} />
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```